# I want to display on children categories name of a particular category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display only children categories of a particular category.
Suppose I have a category "city" and its children categories are "london" and "new york".

I want to display these children by mentioning parent's name.

Searched codex on wordpress website but not helpful. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're talking about isn't it? http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories pay particular attention to 'child_of' parameter to select (the id) of your parent category.

Comment: am sorry, the id is tag ID of the category ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that will do the trick - you should be able to find it in the URL of the admin panel, as well as a couple other areas I'm sure.

Comment: I have written a line of code and the ID of that particular category is 3.
<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=3'); ?> 

but it doesnt show anything

Comment: wp_list_categories(array('child_of' => 3));

Comment: OMG, what a silly mistake I did. Thanks a ton mikevoermans :)